# Make script run reliably from context menu

Tags: windows, cmd, command, contextmenu

I want to delete files from a list stored in a text file from a context menu in windows 7. I worked out the command, and it works fine if I run the script in command prompt in the directory I want to clean.

I want to make the script accessible via context menu so when I right click on the folder and click on the shortcut command, it will delete the files in that folder listed in a separate text file. This is what I've tried:

I put my command in registry. It showed up, but does not run as I expected. This is my command:

```
for /f %i in (D:\Desktop\Documents\deletelist.txt) do del %i
```

This is the registry command:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe for /f %i in (D:\Desktop\Documents\deletelist.txt) do del %i
```

After I clicked this on the context menu, the command prompt window switches the current directory to C:\Windows\system32\ and doesn't run anything. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this?

Edit:

Sorry if I didn't make myself clear here. The command will run in C:\Windows\system32\ because no current directory was passed as parameter. It runs fine if I go to the path I want and run it. Not ok if the directory is dynamic.

I gave up on that approach. Back to batch, I guess. My registry entry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\Delete files\command]
@="\"D:\\Desktop\\Documents\\delfil.bat\" %1"
```

And my bat file:

```
start /D %1 /B for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (D:\Desktop\Documents\deletelist.txt) do del /q "%%i"
exit
```

It works but using start leaves the command window stay up and not auto closed. Also, I can't delete folders and files indiscriminally. For example, I have a deletelist.txt look like this:

```
Pale Moon temp
Temp
007_copy.jpg
008_copy.jpg
009_copy.jpg
010_copy.jpg
011_copy.jpg
012_copy.jpg
013_copy.jpg
014_copy.jpg
015_copy.jpg
016_copy.jpg
017_copy.jpg
018_copy.jpg
019_copy.jpg
020_copy.jpg
021_copy.jpg
022_copy.jpg
credits.jpg
lol.reg
```

There are 2 folders and the other are files. If I run (del /q "%%i"), the files in current folder and subfolders are deleted but the subfolders are remained. I have to run a separate batch with (rd /s /q "%%i") to get rid of the folders. Any clean way to just run a command to scan the list, grab the line, and delete the item regardless if it is folder or file.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to work an echo command into your registry script?

Answer (score 0):

you simply forgot the parameter `/c`:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "for /f %i in (D:\Desktop\Documents\deletelist.txt) do del %i"
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post to make it clearer. The command you gave will not work if using as context menu shortcut. It will jump to C:\Windows\system32\ and run there, finding non-exist files and folders in the list.

Answer (score 0):

just posted an answer here [How to add batch script to context menu of multiple computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735263/how-to-add-batch-script-to-context-menu-of-multiple-computers/31755431) that addresses some of your issues.

So for you something like

```
cmd /c cd "%V% & <the rest of your commands>
```

`&` seperates commands on the same line. In the REGISTRY ONLY `%V%` is the directory if you are on the background menu, use `%1` if you are right clicking a folder.

You can run your commands twice, once with `rd` and once with `del`. It doesn't hurt anything. Seperate them with an ampersand (`&`).